# Error in accessing post json data in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Am passing data to yii2 using ajax request but i keep on getting a 500 error

This is the ajax request code:

```
<?php 
 $script = <<< JS

     $('form#forward_pr').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
    var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
     $.post({
       url: "forwardpr", // your controller action
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {keylist: keys},
       success: function(data) {
          alert('I did it! Processed checked rows.')
       },
     error: function(err){
       console.log("server error");
       }
    });
       return false;
    }  ) ;

    JS;
    $this->registerJS($script);
 ?>
```

When i do console.log(keys) this returns

```
[0, 1]
```

This is my controller code:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
         echo $post = json_encode($_POST['keys']);
          if (isset($_POST['keylist'])) {
                $keys = \yii\helpers\Json::decode($_POST['keylist']);
              print_r($keys);
            }else{
              echo "1";
          }
```

The above always executes the error part of post request, What could be wrong;

Comment: add json encoded string you want to decode.

Comment: Please post the exact code

Comment: sorry skull i want to decode the values of $keys

Comment: Try to change ajax url like controller/method and try once please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are sending your JSON as encoded (post) data body, not key value pairs. So your approach is not working this way.

There are two options to fix this:

1. refactor your controller into a [RESTful service](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)
2. in your controller use the JSON body rather than POST parameters

While the first option is preferred in the long run, the second option is pretty simple as a quick fix.

First, make sure you configure your app to parse JSON body conten.
IN `config.php` add this to the `components` array:

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

Then in your controller use this to get the JSON parameters:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams());
```

Comment: Thanks i had to change it to rest api form

Comment: Great answer!! Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie.. But I also want use checkboxcoloumns in gridview (Kartik version).
1st thing.

Instead of writing

```
var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

I have to write

```
var keys = $('#w4').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

2nd thing.
In the controller you can process the keylist, but don't try to decode it, simple use it int this way:

```
        $keys = $_POST['keylist'];
```

and it seems it works for me!

Sorry for my english..