# Getting null in return when executing Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Ajax request is executing, but it returns not curent_day variable but null.

Js:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'planing/next-day',
            data: {new_curent_day: $('.owl-item.center .slide_day').text()},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(curent_day) {
                alert(curent_day);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
            }
        });
```

Controller:

```
public function actionNextDay() {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            $this->planing_model->curent_day = Yii::$app->request->post('new_curent_day');
            return Json::encode($this->planing_model->curent_day);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your server side implementation and figure out that, why the value is getting null?

Comment: what type of html element is .slide_day? If it is an input field try this $('.owl-item.center .slide_day').val();

Comment: No, it is <span> element

Comment: put echo statement as echo $this->planing_model->curent_day also verify url 'planing/next-day'

Comment: If i put "echo" then i get exception "parsererror|
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: check for the real reasult of  $('.owl-item.center .slide_day').text()  in your $.ajax function  .. seems that you are accessing a collection and not a single item

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is your are sending the POST data as JSON so your not able get it through

```
Yii::$app->request->post('new_curent_day');
```

Try this they have updated JSON parser set and to get the JSON value through yii.

[Error in accessing post json data in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786511/error-in-accessing-post-json-data-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript console and debugger in your browser to see what `$('.owl-item.center .slide_day')` contains. Make your API endpoint log what it gets in the post variables.

The typos in variable names make me worry that you might refer to the wrong thing. planing has two n's, curent has two r's. This code looks consistent at least but if I came across this code I would suspect *current* and *curent* got mixed up.

Comment: Selector is correct, Request sends variable that looks like "new_curent_day=26", but server returns null.

Comment: According to variable names - i have checked all paths, they are correct too

Comment: Check if $this->planing_model->curent_day in the controller isn't empty

Comment: It's default value generates in init(), so it isn't

Comment: try to print you post variable into the controller, ot var_dump(Json::encode($this->planing_model->curent_day));

Comment: It returns exactly what i need - this variable. So i think that the problem is in this string: $this->planing_model->curent_day = Yii::$app->request->post('new_curent_day');

Comment: But your error is clear,  you have a problem when you encode your json

Comment: I meant it retuns variable if i comment this string, else it returns this exception: https://i.gyazo.com/d92b7941db27a8392d4ace342d46956c.png

Comment: Well, if i change my request to GET method and add in controller variable $new_curent_day and then use it like $this->planing_model->curent_day = $new_curent_day; it works. So, what is the problem with POST method?

Comment: var_dump(Yii::app()->request->post);